# Need Fake ETH (Goerli Testnet)

Tags: ether, goerli

Hi can someone give me fake ETH (Goerli Tesnet). I am a university student, and I don't have 0.001 ETH (a requirement to receive fake ETH from GOERLY FAUCET website). My Goerli Testnet address is below:

0x27Db773862C436ee1248298F1AD484b0429e64B2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is some kind of scam but there are free faucets. Also Goerli is becoming deprecated at the end of the year. Use Sepolia.

use:
https://goerlifaucet.com/
or:
https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/

Comment: The first link I have already tried but they are avoiding bots and you need to have 0.001 ETH to request. The second one you need to mining to gain ETH, it is not free, but I think it solves my issue, thanks. In addition is a Deutschland (.de) website?

Comment: not sure about the .de could just be vanity